# Proof about cosets

Tags: group-theory

C In parts 1-5 below, $G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove the following (Theorem 5 will play a crucial role)

**Theorem 5-** Let G be a group and H be a subgroup of G. Then

$(i)$    $Ha= Hb\quad\text{iff}\quad ab^{-1}\in H$

$(ii)$    $Ha = a\quad\text{iff}\quad a\in H$

1. if $x^2\in H$ for every $x\in G$, then every element of $G/H$ is its own inverse. Conversely, if every element of $G/H$ is its own inverse, then $x^2\in H$ for all $x\in G$.
2. Suppose that for every $x\in G$, there is an integer $n$, such that $x^n\in H$; then every element of $G/H$ has finite order.  Conversely, if every element of $G/H$ has finite order, then for every $x\in G$ there is an integer $n$, such that $x^n\in H$.

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward. Just use the definition of a quotient group.

Comment: First, you should really go to the FAQ and read how to properly type mathematics in this site using LaTeX. Second, in your (ii) I'm guessing you actually meant $\,Ha=H\,$ . Third, try at least to introduce more order in your post using freely spaces, lines, etc. between statements. Fourth and last, and perhaps more important than the above: give us some of your ideas, insights, own effort on the above. This is a very basic question in group theory and it's important you make your own work. After that we can focus on your main problems

Comment: Im not sure how to start either problem?  How do i use the definition to prove this

Comment: For $(ii)$, do you mean $Ha=H$?

Answer (score 0):

You must understand how the quotient group $\,G/H\,$ is defined when $\,H\triangleleft G\,$ , though you **don't need** normality to prove (i)-(ii): this is true for *any* subgroup.

Now, if $\,x\in G\,$  then, *by definition*, in the quotient $\,G/H\,$ we have

$$(xH)^n:=x^nH\Longrightarrow (xH)^2=x^2H=H\Longleftrightarrow x^2\in H$$

and this should get you started for the other questions.